# Convert PDF (with transparency *and* CMYK) to jpg

Tags: php, imagick

I need to generate jpg images from PDF files (first page only). The PDF files are user generated, so they can contain anything. I'm currently using the following code:

```
// Load PDF.
$i = new Imagick;

// Create thumbnail of first page of PDF.
$i->setResolution(150, 150);
$i->loadImage("test.pdf[0]");
$i->thumbnailImage(640, 480, true);

// Remove transparency, fill transparent areas with white rather than black.
$i->setImageBackgroundColor("white");
$i->setImageAlphaChannel(11); // Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_REMOVE
$i->mergeImageLayers(Imagick::LAYERMETHOD_FLATTEN);

// Output.
$i->writeImage("test.jpg");
```

This works as expected in that transparency becomes white instead of black. However, I've run into problems with some generated jpg images, so I ran `jpeginfo` on them:

```
$ jpeginfo -c test.jpg
```

> test.jpg  960 x 480  32bit JFIF  N    9481  Unsupported color conversion request  [ERROR]

It turns out that some source PDFs actually use CMYK, and apparently are not converted to RGB when saved as jpg. So I changed my code to the following (addition of a single line) to explicitly convert to RGB:

```
// Load PDF.
$i = new Imagick;

// Create thumbnail of first page of PDF.
$i->setResolution(150, 150);
$i->loadImage("test.pdf[0]");
$i->thumbnailImage(640, 480, true);

// Remove transparency, fill transparent areas with white rather than black.
$i->setImageBackgroundColor("white");
$i->setImageAlphaChannel(11); // Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_REMOVE
$i->mergeImageLayers(Imagick::LAYERMETHOD_FLATTEN);

// Convert to RGB to prevent creating a jpg with CMYK colors.
$i->setImageColorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_RGB);

// Output.
$i->writeImage("test.jpg");
```

This creates a jpeg with an `RGB` color profile, all right. However, for some obscure reason it results in an image with a **black background** again. In other words: the transparency problem is back. Why does Imagick do this, and more importantly, what's the solution to both the transparency problem and the `CMYK` problem?

Comment: Try to flatten layers before removing alpha channel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct function to use is `transformImageColorspace` not `setImageColorspace`. `transformImageColorspace` is used for existing images, `setImageColorspace` is for new images e.g. svg drawing..

I've added it to the manual and it should show up soon.

Comment: It's amazing! It works! I actually found a little workaround that did the trick, but I'll change my implementation. What I did was `setFormat('png')` and then get the image blob, load the image blob in a new Imagick object, then save as jpg.

Comment: Due to the accuracy of color conversion, It's probably better to use `setColorspace` before loading the PDF file. In that case `transformImageColorspace` is no longer necessary. [LINK](https://github.com/Imagick/imagick/issues/657)