# CMYK Illustrator or PDF file to png with transparency has a white background

Tags: php, ghostscript, imagick

When converting CMYK Illustrator AI or PDF to PNG the transparency get rendered with a white background. When converting a RGB AI or PDF to PNG the transparency remains with the rendered PNG. I have tried implementing the results shown here: [Convert PDF (with transparency *and* CMYK) to jpg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29296779/convert-pdf-with-transparency-and-cmyk-to-jpg) with no success. SVG and PSD files have no problems with transparency getting rendered to PNG from RGB or CYMK.

Our Server has Ghostscript 9.07 installed.

```
$f = $_FILES['imageLoader']['name'];    
$im = new Imagick();
$im->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('transparent'));
$im->readImage("upload/$t/$f");

$width = $im->getImageWidth(); 

if (pathinfo($f, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'psd') {
    $im = $im->mergeImageLayers(Imagick::LAYERMETHOD_FLATTEN);
}

if (pathinfo($f, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'svg') {
    $im->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('transparent'));
    $svg = file_get_contents("upload/$t/$f");
    $im->readImageBlob($svg);
}

if (pathinfo($f, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'ai') {
    $im->transformImageColorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB);
}

if (pathinfo($f, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'pdf') {
    $im->transformImageColorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB);
}


$im->thumbnailImage(149, 240, true);
$im->setImageUnits(imagick::RESOLUTION_PIXELSPERINCH);
$im->setImageResolution(72,72); 
$im->resampleImage(72,72,imagick::FILTER_UNDEFINED,0); 
$im->setImageFormat('png32');
$im->writeImage($outFile);

// clean up
$im->clear();
$im->destroy();
```

CMYK conversion to PNG example:
[image: CMYK conversion to PNG example:]

RGB conversion to PNG example:
[image: RGB conversion to PNG example:]

Update:
Finally got the code working with help from the nice guys at the ImageMagick forum. It appears a problem was to set the colorspace before the image was read. This code now works for me.

```
$im = new Imagick();
$im->setColorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB);
$im->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('transparent'));
$im->readImage("upload/$t/$f");

$width = $im->getImageWidth(); 

if (pathinfo($f, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'psd' ) {
 $im = $im->mergeImageLayers(Imagick::LAYERMETHOD_FLATTEN);
}

if (pathinfo($f, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'svg' ) {
 $im->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('transparent'));
 $svg = file_get_contents("upload/$t/$f");
 $im->readImageBlob($svg);
}

$im->thumbnailImage(149, 240, true);
$im->setImageUnits(imagick::RESOLUTION_PIXELSPERINCH);
$im->setImageResolution(72,72); 
$im->resampleImage(72,72,imagick::FILTER_UNDEFINED,0); 
$im->setImageFormat('png32');
$im->writeImage($outFile);

// cleanup
$im->clear();
$im->destroy();
```

Comment: I'm 'reasonably' certain that ImagMagick will be using Ghostscript to convert the PDF to a PNG file. I would 'suspect' that the problem is CMYK->RGB conversion, this most likely involves 'flattening' the transparency which results in it no longer being transparent. It would help to post an example, and tell us which version of Ghostscript you have installed.

Comment: posting an example input image is definitely a good idea, but also you almost certainly want setImageBackgroundColor rather than setBackgroundColor

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I tried setImageBackgroundColor it unfortunately didn't change anything yet, but I will use it in the final code as soon as I get this problem sorted out.

Comment: ...you need to post an example PDF, so that people can recreate the problem...not just post the final png.

Comment: @Danack I've added two files as links to download. Both are PDF's one in RGB and one in CMYK. We have a t-shirt designer where the user can upload files. This problem occurs with any Postscript file uploaded in CMYK. It can also be tried out here [link] (https://www.dinschrift.ch/en-ch/t-shirt_designer.html) the upload button is still in German and called 'Bild hochladen'. Maybe this might help as well? Thanks for the help if you need anymore information I will gladly provide it.

Comment: Thank for the images - I think this is a problem in ImageMagick itself, so I opened an issue: https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues/220 Any chance you could recreate the pdfs but with not using white text? White text against transparent, in a browser.....with a white background is confusing.

Comment: @Danack I've uploaded new PDF's blue text on a transparent background.

Comment: @Danack I just discovered when saving the PDF and 'Fast Web View' is enabled (in ADOBE) there is no background or colour loss in the conversion from CMYK files. However I am not sure what how this works or what this option actually means. Any clues?

Comment: I think this behaviour is just either a bug or misfeature in ImageMagick. Opening a ticket yourself on their issue tracker is probably the best thing to do.